# Joint density with continuous and binary random variable

Tags: probability-theory

Assume $X\in\mathbb{R}$, $Y\in\{0,1\}$ are two random variables. What allows us to claim that $$f_{X}(x) = f_{XY}(x,1) + f_{XY}(x,0)$$
where $f_X(x)$ and $f_{XY}(x,y)$ are densities.

Comment: The definition, perhaps?

Comment: What is $f_{XY}$ and how does it differ from plain vanilla $f$ which you say is a density?

Comment: My initially posted answer missed something, but I've edited to take that into account, and the answer is still just as simple.

Comment: @ Michael Hardy. Thank you. I upwoted your answer originally, but someone downvoted it after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int_A f_{X,Y}(x,1)+f_{X,Y}(x,0)\,dx & = \int_A f_{X,Y}(x,1)\,dx+\int_A f_{X,Y}(x,0)\,dx \\[8pt]
& = \Pr(X\in A\ \&\ Y=1) + \Pr(X\in A\ \&\ Y=0) \\[8pt]
& = \Pr((X\in A\ \&\ Y=1)\text{ or }(X\in A\ \&\ Y=0)) \\[8pt]
& = \Pr(X\in A) \\[8pt]
& = \int_A f_X(x) \, dx.
\end{align}

Comment: Hi Hardy... He says $X\in \mathbb{R}$, so I thought he was referring to a mixture of discrete and cont. distributions. In that case, $P(X=x,Y=1)$ would become zero.

Comment: Oh, I see.  I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Done. ${{{{{}}}}}$

Answer (score 3):

$$P(X\le x)=P(X\le x\mid Y=1)P(Y=1)+P(X\le x\mid Y=0)P(Y=0)\\
=P(X\le x, Y=1)+P(X\le x,Y=0)\\
f_X(x)=\frac{dP(X\le x)}{dx}=f_{XY}(x,1)+f_{XY}(x,0)$$

Comment: My initial comment here was mistaken; I had missed something.  Now I've adjusted my own answer accordingly.  You've done the derivative version; I've done the integral version.  BTW, I notice I'm the only person who's up-voted the question itself; you might consider doing that.